# How to configure ssh tunneling with Putty between two RHEL servers?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel, rhel6, putty

I'm trying to allow ssh access from a remote RHEL server to a local RHEL box via Win/Putty gateway. Basically, I'd like to be able to do 'ssh localhost -p 512' on a remote server so that it would connect to the RHEL server in the local network. The local network is beyond a firewall so I can connect from my Win PC to the remote server with Putty/ssh but not vice verse.

LclSrv----WinXP/Putty-----||-----RmtSrv

So, I've added the following tunneling settings to the current RmtSrv session in Putty (actually I use Kitty but doesn't matter):

R512 LclSrv:22

I expect that this would create a process on the remote server that listens port 512 and transfers the connections to a local network/LclSrv port 22.

After pressing start button, Putty opens a regular ssh terminal session successfully but nothing happens. (options show active port forwarding). I've checked with netstat -l that port 512 is not listening on RmtSrv. ssh on this port returns 'connection refused'. What am I doing wrong? May be there is something in the sshd_config that needs to be changed in order to allow the tunneling? Could it be user privileges on RmtSrv that prevents me from creating tunnels? I have sudo btw.

Cheers, Vlad.

Comment: Should this be in SuperUser instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Local port forwarding scenario (rmtsrv has access to WinXP):**

What you want to do in ssh terms is forward a local port to another machine and allow other hosts (rmtsrv) to connect to it.

So you set up local WinXP:512 to forward to lclsrv:22.

So in Putty's Tunnel settings be sure to check `Local ports accept connections from other hosts` and add `source port 512` with the destination `lclsrv:22` to the forwarded ports.

**Edit to accommodate comment:
Remote port forwarding scenario (WinXP has access to both srvs):**

The configuration you suggest should work.

```
r512 LclSrv:22
```

Is correct.
I'd guess the issue is with the sshd security settings on rmtsrv. Check if this is enabled:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

If you want to enable access to the forwarded port for others on rmtsrvs network:

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

The config usually resides in '/etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: This will not work because RmtSrv cannot establish connecting with the WinXP machine due to the firewall settings. The opposite is possible however.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood your question, so I extended the answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks, "AllowTcpForwarding yes" solved the issue.

Comment: Happy to help. Not to bug you, but could you set the answer to accepted then?

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of the Putty window you have a Menu. On it, SSH has a + to its left. Click there. Go to Tunnels. Configure them. Voilà.

Comment: Yes, I've done this but it doesn't work. It works however on my home Ubuntu, so I assume that it has something to do with the authority or sshd configuration in RHEL.